# For loop in C for reading number of sequence from text file

Tags: c, for-loop

I was reading about loops in C, I found an interesting line of code, which I could not really understand. I would appreciate if someone could explain me this line:
`for (; count>0; count--, j++)`

But the whole code was like this:

```
while(getline(&line, &count, input) != -1) 
{
  for ( ; count>0; count--, j++)
    sscanf(line, "%d", &array[i]);
  i++;
}
```

The variable `count` is `size_t` type, `int i,j = 0`  and `FILE *input;` for  reading a sequence of numbers stored in text file.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Near nothing in that code makes any sense at all. Even if lines are repeated read from `input`, that `sscanf` inside the loop just repeatedly reads the same `int` value (the first one in `line`) into some `array` at position `i`, which doesn't change throughout the loop. `j` is unused anywhere but a seemingly useless post-increment in the for-loop, and `i` is only incremented *after* the for loop terminates. Finally, `count` is a *byte count* of the `getline` results.

Comment: Are you sure that this is the entire code? Because this doesn't really do anything meaningful.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya I didn't post entire source file because it's too long, i only briefly wrote the part of the variables, and the confusing part of the code, which is also start of file, where it reads the sequence of numbers from text file, then, it implies those numbers as an array actually. which is continuing  with different function for finding each number how many time represented in the array, and so on different function

Comment: the posted code is nonsense.  It repeatedly retrieves the first number in the input 'line` and places that number in successive locations in the array `array[i]`. Note: variable `j` gets incremented  until it reaches the initial value in `count`  It would have been much simpler to just do: `j = count;` before the `for()`  loop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While a traditional `for` loop looks like `for(i = 0; i < N; i++)` this is also a valid way to use it.

- The first part of the loop is empty because it's not needed
  (`for(;;)` is also valid).
- The second part (`count>0;`) is the stop condition as you would expect
- The third part is what is done in the end of each iteration, and in this case - that's 2 things (can be 0 commands, or any other number of commands): `count--, j++`

A `for` loop can be used with 0,1 or 2 of it *parts* used, meaning all of these options are OK:

1. `for(;;)`
2. `for(int i;;)` only declaration. A bit odd, but valid
3. `for(int i=0; i < 10;)` also valid, but this could be an infinite loop
4. `for(int i=0; ; i++)` also valid, but this could be an infinite loop since no stop condition is present (a `break` inside the loop can handle this)
5. `for(int i=0;i<10;i++)` traditional
6. `for(;i<10;i++)` valid if `i` is declared elsewhere (it also should be defined...)
7. `for(;i<10;)` only stop condition, odd, but valid
8. `for(;;i++)` also valid if `i` is declared elsewhere, but this could be an infinite loop

Another thing that should be noted: since any number of statements can be used in each part of the for loop, you could have something like:

```
    for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < 1, j < 5; i++, j++)
        printf("%d\t%d\n", i, j);
```

Note that using `,` is tricky. It will execute each of the statements but only evaluate the last, meaning that in each of the 3 parts of the loop:

1. `int i = 0, j = 0;` both will execute. No evaluation relevant
2. **TRICKY PART**`i < 1, j < 5` both will execute *BUT* only `j < 5` will be evaluated, meaning, the loop stop condition is `j < 5`. `i < 1` is written there, but that will not make the loop stop
3. `i++, j++` same as 1. Both will execute. No evaluation relevant

And this is the output:

```
0       0
1       1
2       2
3       3
4       4
```

Answer (score 2):

`for (; count>0; count--, j++)` means:

- do nothing `(;`;
  this is where usually the loop control variables are initialised,
  but if that is already done, it is fine to do nothing
- start looping

  - if count is great than 0, `count>0;`, then do the body,
    else continue after the body
  - then decrement count and increment j `count--, j++)`
- loop

Answer (score 0):

Since he already declared the variable he wish to increment, he does not redeclare it in the for loop. He also change two variables at each turn of the loop, he decrement count and increment j. [sscanf definition](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_sscanf.htm) if you need. He basically read a file.

Answer (score 0):

Let's examine the code line that confuses you.

```
for (; count>0; count--, j++){
    statement
}
```

executes `statement` while `count>0`. It repeatly does `count--, j++` where `,` is the *comma operator*. This operator does the following:

```
expression1, expression2
```

evalutes `expression1` , then evaluates `expression2` and returns the value of `expression2` as the value of the whole expression.

Since the value of `count--,j--` is not used here, this is just doing `count--` followed by `j--`.

Every argument of a `for`-loop is optional therefore even `for(;;)` is valid and equivalent to `while(1)`.